# Devise - Respond with resource and custom errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I only want some users to be able to reset their passwords provided they have a flag set against their profile. I have the current code

```
 class PasswordsController < Devise::PasswordsController

  def create
    self.resource = resource_class
    u = User.find_or_initialize_with_errors([:email], resource_params, :not_found)
    if u.try(:group).nil?
      super
    else
      #respond_with(resource)
      redirect_to :new_user_password, notice: "Your password is managed by your team leader, please contact them."
    end
  end
end
```

Although it's commented out above, I am trying to respond with the resource, just as devise does in it's code. If I respond with the current resource I get `undefined method`users_url'`, how can I solve this?

Also, what is the best way to add errors to this resource so that `devise_error_messages!` will display them correctly.